# Cox proportional hazards with time-dependent covariates: predict in R

Tags: r, cox-model

I would like to use the predict function (or something similar) in R to generate expected values from a Cox proportional hazards model with time-dependent covariates. The model takes the form

```
model <- coxph(Surv(start,stop,event.time)~covars..., data=data)
```

Normally, it's pretty straightforward to predict expected values by generating a new data frame where the covariates are all held at some value, except for one of interest (in this case, age). But when I use

```
newdata <- with(data, data.frame(acovar<-values, bcovar<-values...)
y <- predict(model, newdata, type="expected")
```

I get an error that says that the "Time" variable is not numeric. I have seen workarounds to this (i.e., be explicit about data source) for ordinary Cox PH, but don't know what to do for Cox PH with time-dependent covariates.

The data look something like this

```
 start     stop     event.time     acovar     bcovar
 0         1        1              m          1
 1         2        0              f          1
 2         3        0              f          1
```